# Import .FBX into android studio with no materials

Tags: arcore, 3dsmax, fbx

I am new at ARcore, and I am learning it right now.
i am following a tutorial to build my first ARcore app.
Heres the link https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2xkZUPUbgoM

this tutorial works very well, but when i try to add my custom fbx object in to my project, there is no material at all, just like this: 
[picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cb66N.jpg)
but the fbx object in the tutorial works very fine and like this.
[picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mHKft.jpg)
i've been noticed that it will create a .fbm directory when i import sceneform asset. but i selected embed media when i export my obj in to .fbx at 3ds max, it should suppose with a material inside .fbx
i need help

the fbx file:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=173TislIayOSBTzuesVJXE81MeByy_aKF

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem might be in the type of material.
The bear is using[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FflIf.jpg) a standard material and you are using a generic